# selenium python chromedriver download zip file

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to download zip files(sample domains) of [this](https://whoisds.com/newly-registered-domains) site.

My code is like below

```
import pandas
import requests
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
             'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'

project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": project_dir,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
options.headless = True

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    # --- download the sample domain zip files ---
    driver.get("https://whoisds.com/newly-registered-domains")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    zip_file_link = '//td/a[contains(@href, "newly-registered-domains")]'
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(zip_file_link)
    for link in links:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
        time.sleep(50)
        # I am not sure below code is necessary or not.
        # -----------------------------------------
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(project_dir, 'r')
        zip_ref.extractall(project_dir)
        zip_ref.close()
        # -----------------------------------------
....
```

But it shows the error like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "whois.py", line 51, in <module>
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(project_dir, 'r')
      File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1207, in __init__
        self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\Project\\whois.com'
```

I've read many posts of StackOverflow but I couldn't find the correct way.
Please teach me how to download zip files.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might need to specify the path to the chromedriver executable, and also make sure it isn't being used by any other processes at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for you response. But I think this issue is not related the path of chromedriver. I edited my post, so please read again and let me know why this issue happens.